# Getting right value from $wpdb

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

Before creating new post programmatically I want to check if there is a post with the same headline in my database.

I am checking that like this:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'candidates' AND post_title = '$name'");
```

Example of value I get when I var_dump($results):

> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#85 (1) { ["COUNT(*)"]=> string(1) "8" } }

Now I want to get that `string(1) "8"`, add it to variable and convert it to number, but I am not sure how to get it.

I tried something like

```
$number = (int)$results[0]->COUNT(*)
```

but that isn't right. I also tried some other combinations but couldn't figure it out

Comment: I think the problem is `(*)`. Use an alias in your query. `SELECT COUNT(*) as post_count FROM $wpdb->posts ...` and `$number = (int) $results[0]->post_count`

Comment: You are right! Thank you very much @CharlotteDunois :) Add this comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your very problem is the `(*)` in `$number = (int)$results[0]->COUNT(*)`. You cannot use these special characters simply as 'variable'. You're better off using a column alias using `AS your_column_alias`.

So you want to use

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as post_count FROM $wpdb->posts  WHERE post_type = 'candidates' AND post_title = '$name'
```

as query and

```
$number = (int) $results[0]->post_count;
```

to fetch the aliased column from your resultset.